# How to silence the warning in the Archive::Zip

Tags: perl

I do not want to see the following messages when extracting archive.

```
format error: file is too short at /usr/share/perl5/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 667.    
Archive::Zip::Archive::_findEndOfCentralDirectory('Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x8acf47c)', 'IO::File=GLOB(0x8ac9d70)') called at /usr/share/perl5/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 581
Archive::Zip::Archive::readFromFileHandle('Archive::Zip::Archive=HASH(0x8acf47c)', 'IO::File=GLOB(0x8ac9d70)', 'some zip file') called at /usr/share/perl5/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 548
```

I want to skip some corrupted archives.

Comment: Add your code that produces this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very untidy to mess with the SIGWARN handler or redirect the STDERR output to the null device.

`Archive::Zip` has a function to set the error handler `Archive::Zip::setErrorHandler`. The default is to use `Carp::carp`, which produces the output you're seeing.

You can write your own replacement, for instance to save the error messages in an array for later examination, like this

```
my @errors;
Archive::Zip::setErrorHandler(sub { push @errors, $_[0] });
```

Also don't forget to check the return codes from the functions as there will otherwise be no way to know that there has been a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on where you are calling the function that emits this error, you can override the warning handler locally to ignore the warnings.

```
sub f {
   ...
   local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { # do nothing };
}
```

Now all warnings emitted in function f get routed to your local warn handler, which does nothing.

You should note that Archive::Zip has an error flag `AZ_OK` that is returned from most operations. For instance:

```
# Read a Zip file
my $somezip = Archive::Zip->new();
if ( $somezip->read( 'someZip.zip' ) != AZ_OK ) {
    die 'read error';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
`command-to-extract-file 2>/dev/null`
```

Pipes stderr to /dev/null

This works for linux. Not sure about windows??